# How to get authorisation code during angularfire installation?

Tags: angular, firebase

During installation [AngularFire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire) by `ng add @angular/fire` I get following error

```
? Paste authorization code here: 1//0cpKD...
Authentication Error: Your credentials are no longer valid. Please run firebase login --reauth

For CI servers and headless environments, generate a new token with firebase login:ci
```

I try do put different code-like string from firebase site but no luck. I also try to run  `firebase login:ci`, this generate long url, I copy it to browser and login to my google account, accept, and copy quite long token - but still no luck - it is wrong. How to get right authorization code?

Comment: Despite solving this problem, I gave up using angularfire - because this library throws errors during compilation ina Angualr 13 (and has some problems with TypeScript - and nobody knows when they fix it) - and - what is more important - this library actually not simplify anything. Using raw firebase lib you can easily init it (usnig environment) and convert its Promises to Obserwables using rxjs `from(your_promise)` operator...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found following solution (which works on my macOs: Monterey):

1. Run `firebase login:ci --no-localhost`
2. and open in browser generated link, login to your google account and accept
3. copy code (which is few times shorter than token (~62 chars)
4. TRICK: do NOT PASTE that code to console - but open new separate console
5. In new console run `ng add @angular/fire`
6. and paste that code during installation - now error not appear

Comment: For me this one worked, and the answer from seelvek didn't... Guess you'll have to try them both and see which one works for you. :D

Answer (score 29):

What worked for me was to login to firebase.

So my steps that worked were following:

1. Run `firebase login:ci` and follow instructions
2. Run `firebase login` -> select your account, project etc...
3. Run `ng add @angular/fire` -> it should ask you for what account to use, instead asking for authorization code

Had this issue today, first time using Firebase.

Comment: Indeed this works man! , the accepted one fails